# Why does p:panelGrid not work with ui:repeat?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

If I use as below, I get no error, no output.
Why does `p:panelGrid` not work with `ui:repeat`?

**Note** : I don't want to use `c:forEach` because of the I already face a lot of JSF issue.

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <ui:repeat value="#{MyBean.dataList}" var="data">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{data.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{data.description}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panelGrid>
```

MyBean.java

```
public List<Data> getDataList(){
    List<Data> result = new ArrayList<Data>();
    result.add(new Data("Name 1", "Description 1"));
    result.add(new Data("Name 2", "Description 2"));
    result.add(new Data("Name 3", "Description 3"));
    result.add(new Data("Name 4", "Description 4"));
    return result;
}
```

Expected output with primefaces

[image]

Comment: Why not use p:dataTable instead? p:panelGrid is meant for static tables.

Comment: @mrembisz I cannot use it because of my user interface. if you would like my user interface, I will upload

Comment: You seem to be not understanding the difference between taghandlers and UI components. Using `c:forEach` should not be feared, but should be *understood* instead. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @BalusC thanks I will reference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ui:repeat` will not work because it does not actually add components to the component tree.

`ui:repeat` only works during the render phase, and rerenders its child components multiple times with different state.

Some components, such as `panelgrid`, but also `datatable`, expect to have certain children in the component tree in order to work correctly.  Since `ui:repeat` does not add these, this approach does not work.

I'm sorry, but the normal solution for this is to use `c:foreach`, which *does* add children to the tree.

See https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Try it by defining `columns` in `p:panelGrid` as you have static number columns then you should have to define `<p:panelGrid columns="">`.It will work.
But I suggest you to use `primefaces datatable` for this

```
<p:dataTable id="availableCars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">  
    <p:column style="width:20px">  
        <h:outputText id="dragIcon"  
            styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4" />  
        <p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Model">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Color">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

[Here is the link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dndTable.jsf) from where you can find this code and primnefaces showcase.I think it will fulfill your requirment

Comment: Thanks, It cannot meet my expected output. Reference my picture in question.

Comment: Please, I upload my new image for my expected output. How can I use datatable.

Comment: For this , I sugest you to just use simple HTML table with colspan and rowspan